# Pgfplots: How to get the data to be shown by hours instead of days?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dateplot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pgfplot: Datafile format for datetime field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9733/pgfplot-datafile-format-for-datetime-field)

The solution to the following problem is probably very straightforward, but I've yet to find the right solution.

I'm trying generate a plot from data consisting of 358 lines looking like this:

```
2011-12-02 02:00:00, 14.43
2011-12-02 04:00:00, 4.49
2011-12-02 06:00:00, 12.33
2011-12-02 08:00:00, 4.23
2011-12-02 10:00:00, 2.49
2011-12-02 12:00:00, 2.26
2011-12-02 14:00:00, 2.32
```

I'm using the following code to generate the plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotstableread{/home/user/data/csv/servername.cpud3}
\cputable
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
axis background/.style={fill,bottom color=gray!50,top color=white},
grid=major,
grid style={dotted,black},
width=15cm,
height=8cm,
date coordinates in=x,
date ZERO=2011-12-02 02:00:00,
xmin =2011-12-02 02:00:00,
xmax =2011-12-31 20:00:00,
xtick=data,
minor tick num=12,
ymax =100,
ylabel=\%,
xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=near xticklabel}
]
\addplot[ycomb] table[ y index = 2 ] from \cputable ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This produces the following graph:
[image]

How do I get the data to be plotted for every second hour instead of days without changing the `xticklabels`?

Jake's comment below solved my problem.

Working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{/home/user/data/csv/server.cpud3}
\cputable
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
axis background/.style={fill,bottom color=gray!50,top color=white},
grid=major,
grid style={dotted,black},
width=15cm,
height=8cm,
date coordinates in=x,
date ZERO=2011-12-02 02:00:00,
xmin =2011-12-02 02:00:00,
xmax =2011-12-31 20:00:00,
xtick=,
minor tick num=12,
ymax =100,
ylabel=\%,
xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=near xticklabel}
]
\addplot[ycomb] table[ y index = 1 ] from \cputable ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Rasmus, welcome to TeX.sx! It's always a good idea to post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. a full file that can be compiled. In this case, your minimal example could contain the data inline in the `\addplot` command. I've tried to reproduce your result, but for me, the data is plotted correctly. Note that `xtick=data` is almost definitely not what you want in this case, since it would generate a tick for every data point. Could you try to create a full minimal example?

Comment: In your real file, do you use `\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]...`?

Comment: Jake! Thanks. The missing [col sep=comma] was the issue! Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @Jake Is it meaningful to make this an answer, or should we close?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: I think this can be closed as a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9734/2552