# How do I include data files in a TikZ drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to include the following data which is now in a separate `doses.data` file

```
0   1
10  1
11  1
12  1
0   2
1   2
4.8 2
```

into my `TikZ` drawing. Right now I'm importing the file, but I want the actual data inside my `tikzpicture` environment:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%<
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.2cm, x=.7cm,font=\rmfamily]
    %axis
    \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (21,0);
        %ticks
        \foreach \x in {0,...,21}
            \draw (\x,0pt) -- (\x,-3pt)
            node[anchor=north] {\x};
    %labels      
    \node[below=0.8cm] at (x axis mid) {Dose [Gy]};

    \draw plot[mark=*, only marks, mark size=2] 
        file {doses.data};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To clarify, I don't want to include `file {doses.data};`, but the contents of `doses.data` instead. What is the correct syntax to do this?

**Edit:** If there's a simpler solution to this with `pgfplots`, I'm in, but I'd prefer TikZ since I would like to add things later on.

Comment: You can always use TikZ “to add things later on” with the `axis cs` coordinate system. (→ `pgfplots` manual, subsection 4.16.1 “Accessing Axis Coordinates in Graphical Elements”, pp. 255f.)

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question correctly but [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9733/pgfplot-datafile-format-for-datetime-field) might help. It also uses tikzpicture environment.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to write `file {doses.data};`, but the contents of `doses.data` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can embed like this:

```
\draw plot[mark=*, only marks, mark size=2] coordinates {(0,1) (10,1) (11,1) (12,1) (0,2) (1,2) (4.8,2)};
```

## OR:

A better way, in which no modification of coordinates is needed:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{doses.data}
    # Header goes here
    0   1
    10  1
    11  1
    12  1
    0   2
    1   2
    4.8 2
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.2cm, x=.7cm,font=\rmfamily]
    \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (21,0);
        \foreach \x in {0,...,21}
            \draw (\x,0pt) -- (\x,-3pt)
            node[anchor=north] {\x};
    \node[below=0.8cm] at (x axis mid) {Dose [Gy]};
    \draw plot[mark=*, only marks, mark size=2] file {doses.data};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this technique still use file. File created by the LaTeX itself on the first run. Standard version of `filecontents` environment **did not** update files upon modification of appropriate content, it would be better to use package `filecontents` which does.

Comment: I went with the first version, once typed in, I don't need to change the coordinates.