# pgfplots - how to draw seconds from csv in hours:minute format?

Tags: pgfplots

I have data in a `.csv` file with seconds as `x` values. I'd like to tick the `x` axis in hours:minute formate e.g.: `0:00` , `0:30` , `1:00` , `1:30` ...

How do I have to redefine the interpretation of values to fit into that different presentation style?

data sample

```
    seconds values
    30       3.98
    60       3.97
    90       3.96
    120      3.96
    150      3.95
    ...      ...
   3210      3.45
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Especially some example data would be helpful.

Comment: So your x coordinates are simply seconds, not minutes:seconds, right?

Comment: jepp, just seconds like x column: 560 y column: 3.98

Comment: See [pgfplots data time format](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79252/4778) and [pgfplot: Datafile format for datetime field](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9733/4778). Also see [How to plot data from a CSV file using tikz and csvsimple?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83888/4778)

Comment: @Alenanno: All those examples address a different problem, where the time is formatted using `minutes:seconds`.

Comment: @Jake Going from "minute:second" to "hour:minute" is not harder than going from "zero" to that. :D I think they are helpful in this case.

Comment: @Alenanno: i already found this posts before posting my question. the problem here is to tell pgfplots to interpret value a as b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the seconds to hours by using an `x filter`, and then split the hours and minuts for the labels within the `xticklabel` expression:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    % Convert seconds to hours
    x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1/3600}},
    xticklabel={ % Split into hours and minutes
        \pgfmathsetmacro\hours{floor(\tick)}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\minutes{(\tick-\hours)*0.6}%
        % Use some trickery to get leading zeros
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\hours}:\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, fixed zerofill, skip 0.=true, dec sep={}]{\minutes}%
    },
    xtick={0,0.25,...,1}
]
\addplot table {
    seconds values
    30       3.98
    60       3.97
    90       3.96
    120      3.96
   3210      3.95
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```